# trying to delete a data after repopulating

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to delete a data after using it to pre-populate a form, but it is deleting before pre-populating the form. though it repopulates  well , but when i try deleting the data after using it by inserting if($queryreg !== false){
            $deletetable = mysql_query("DELETE FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
        }
        ?> 
it simply does not work

```
    <?php
    $submit = $_POST['Add'];

    //form data
    $Sname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Sname'])));
    $Pname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pname'])));
    $Pidno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pidno'])));
    $Psize = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Psize'])));
    $Pcolour = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pcolour'])));
    $Pquantity = $_POST['Pquantity'];
    $Weblink = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Weblink'])));
    $Price = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Price'])));
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['comment'])));
    $date = date("Y-m-d");


//echo "          

    ('','$Sname','$Pname','$Pidno','$Psize','$Pcolour','$Pquantity','$Weblink','$Price','$Uname')";
    if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) 

    {
    if ($Sname&&$Pname&&$Pidno&&$Weblink&&$Price)
    {
    if (is_numeric($Price))
    {
    $repeatheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname =       
    '{$_SESSION['username']}' AND Pidno ='$Pidno' AND Sname='$Sname' AND Pname='$Pname'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($repeatheck);
    if($count!=0)
    {
    die ('PRODUCT ALREADY IN BASKET YOU CAN INCREASE OR DECREASE QUANTITY, <a        
    href="youraccount.php">CLICK TO GO BACK TO YOUR LIST</a>');
    }
    else
//echo'$Price';
    $tprice = $Price * $Pquantity;
//echo"$tprice";
    $queryreg = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO repplac VALUES                            

        ('','$Sname','$Pname','$Pidno','$Psize','$Pcolour','$Pquantity','$Weblink','$Price','$comment'  
    ,'$tprice','$date','{$_SESSION['username']}','')
    ")or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    echo 'price field requires numbers';
    }
    else
    echo 'please fill in all required * fields ';
    }
     if($queryreg !== false){
        $deletetable = mysql_query("DELETE FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
    }
    ?>


     <form action='youraccount.php' method='Post' class='ilistbar'>
        <!--<div>
        <label for='shoppinglist' class='fixedwidth'></label>
        <textarea type='text' name='shoppinglist' id='username' cols='100' rows='15'>      
    </textarea>
        </div> -->
        <div>
    <label for='Sname' class='fixedwidth'> * Shop name</label>
    <input type='text' name='Sname' id='Sname' value='<?php $addprodresult =                  
     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or    
    die(mysql_error());$row = mysql_fetch_array($addprodresult); echo $row{Sname}; ?>'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Pname' class='fixedwidth'> * Product name</label>
    <input type='text' name='Pname' id='Pname' value='<?php $addprodresult =    
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or 
    die(mysql_error());$row = mysql_fetch_array($addprodresult); echo $row{Pname}; ?>'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Pidno' class='fixedwidth'> * Product id no /ad reference</label>
    <input type='text' name='Pidno' id='Pidno' value='<?php $addprodresult = 
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or   
    die(mysql_error());$row = mysql_fetch_array($addprodresult); echo $row{Pidno}; ?>'/>
    (This should be unique for each product)
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Psize' class='fixedwidth'>Product size</label>
    <input type='text' name='Psize' id='Psize' value='<?php $addprodresult = 
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or 
    die(mysql_error());$row = mysql_fetch_array($addprodresult); echo $row{Psize}; ?>'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Pcolour' class='fixedwidth'>Product colour</label>
    <input type='text' name='Pcolour' id='Pcolour' value='<?php $addprodresult = 
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or 
    die(mysql_error());$row = mysql_fetch_array($addprodresult); echo $row{Pcolour}; ?>'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Pquantity' class='fixedwidth'>Product quantity</label>
        <select name="Pquantity" id="Pquantity">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option> 
</select>
(You can update quantity in excess of 10 on the shopping list below)
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Weblink' class='fixedwidth'> * Web link</label>
    <input type='text' name='Weblink' id='Weblink' value='<?php $addprodresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());$row = mysql_fetch_array($addprodresult); echo $row{Weblink}; ?>'/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='Price' class='fixedwidth'> * Price GBP</label>
    <input type='text' name='Price' id='Price' value='<?php $addprodresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'") or die(mysql_error());$row = mysql_fetch_array($addprodresult); echo $row{Price}; ?>'/>
    Please valid format is (.) for decimal
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for='comment' class='fixedwidth'> Extra info</label>
    <input type='text' name='comment' id='comment'/>
    Please give different colours , sizes of the same products,discount codes, and other information that you would like us to use
    </div>
    <div>

    <div class='buttonarea'>
            <p>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'>
            </p>
            </div>
            </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: You have an error after `//echo "`. Fix it. And in the future please  tell us about any errors you have.

Comment: @ Sverri M. Olsen there is no error coming up, it simply delete the data, but when this code                                     if($queryreg !== false){
    $deletetable = mysql_query("DELETE FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
}   is not there it repopulates, but i need it to be deleted from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have been able to delete the data by immediately using the delete query after inserting in the other table

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO repplac VALUES ('','$Sname','$Pname','$Pidno','$Psize','$Pcolour','$Pquantity','$Weblink','$Price','$comment','$tprice','$date','{$_SESSION['username']}','')
")or die(mysql_error());
$deletetable = mysql_query("DELETE FROM addingprod WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
}
```

instead of later in the code